# CSS Button uses multiple rows, rather than 1

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a website, I'm not a professional at css, but it's looking good so far, this is my button, [Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFxLI.png)you see how the three words are split on separate lines? It makes the button taller then I wanted it to be, and it doesn't look nice and makes the site look weird with the rest of the buttons, I want all the words spread on 1 line, making it longer horizontally, rather than vertically,

HTML:

```css
.game1 {
  border: none;
  /*background-color: #f5f5f5;*/
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
  padding: 14px 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 400px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

body {
  background-color: #051321;
}
```

```html
<a href="/takenfronhome.html"><button class="game1 success">Taken From Home</button></a>
```

Comment: add your html code

Comment: add this for css: `white-space: nowrap;` the space between words is called `white-space`. with `nowrap` you forbit a word/line-break.